# Colors in psqlrc based on database being accessed

Tags: psql

I'd like to display a different message if you are connecting to a primary database vs. a replica - maybe use a red prompt on the primary database and a neutral color on the replica.

Is there a way to set this in the `.psqlrc`? something like

```
if `dbname` == 'prod' 
    \set PROMPT1 'danger danger'
else
    \set PROMPT1 'foo'
fi
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it... answer taken from MatheusOl in the #postgresql IRC channel. This code will display a blue prompt if you're on a replica, or a red prompt if you're on a primary node.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN pg_is_in_recovery() 
    THEN '%[%033[33;1m%]%x%[%033[0m%]%[%033[34m%]%/%[%033[0m%]%R%# ' 
    ELSE '%[%033[33;1m%]%x%[%033[0m%]%[%033[31m%]%/%[%033[0m%]%R%# ' 
END AS "PROMPT1" \gset
```

The key difference in there are the 34 (blue ANSI escape sequence) vs 31 (red ANSI escape sequence).

Note that ANSI escape sequences will likely screw with your up/down/keyboard shortcuts if you are using libedit, which is the default on Mac OS X, Postgres.app and older versions of Homebrew. See  [Colors in the psql prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19139330/329700) for slightly more information.

Comment: psql 14.6 says: `warning: attempt to \gset into specially treated variable "PROMPT1" ignored`

Comment: change "PROMPT1" to  prompt, then run
\set PROMPT1 :prompt